# Eclipse cdt, gdb exception cygwin_exception::open_stackdumpfile

Tags: c++, eclipse, gdb

I am using eclipse Mars (4.5.1) CDT. The toolchain is CygwinGCC. I just create a "hello world" c++ code. It compiles but when I am trying to debug. I had following gdb exception:

```
GNU gdb (GDB) (Cygwin 7.10.1-1) 7.10.1
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later 
<http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying" and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-pc-cygwin".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.
For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word".
[New Thread 812.0x560]
[New Thread 812.0x146c]
[New Thread 812.0xd48]
[New Thread 812.0xe54]
[New Thread 812.0x1758]
[Thread 812.0x146c exited with code 0]
[Thread 812.0xe54 exited with code 0]
[Thread 812.0xd48 exited with code 0]
[Thread 812.0x1758 exited with code 0]
[Inferior 1 (process 812) exited normally]
 54 [main] gdb 11012 cygwin_exception::open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace to gdb.exe.stackdump
```

Any hints for fixing the problem?

Thanks,

Rong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exception is thrown when there is no break point is set. CDT is not the best tool for C++ comparing with vs and xcode. But none of them available for Cygwin. I just do not want to install Linux on my pc. So Eclipse is the only thing I can think of :) I got luck this time.